# What is the correct way to call an NgRx loading spinner

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a loading-spinner component where I can show and hide by dispatching NgRx actions like:

`this.store.dispatch(loadingActions.loadingShow());`

`this.store.dispatch(loadingActions.loadingHide());`

Now I can use them in NgRx effects just fine when making API calls. However I would also like to be able to use them in my components where I am listening to store changes using select(). An example scenario is when I need to delay the loadingHide() action until I have completed some processing of the API results in my component, for example:

```
this.dataSource$ = this.store.pipe(
      tap(data => {
        this.store.dispatch(loadingActions.loadingShow());   //this line will cause an infinite loop
      }),
      select(RecordSelectors.selectActiveItems),
      tap(data => {
        //DO SOME PROCESSING HERE

        //hide the loading spinner
        this.store.dispatch(loadingActions.loadingHide());
      })
    );
```

The issue above is when I dispatch the loadingShow action, I am causing the stream to stuck in an endless loop of emitting and listening. So I know the code above is broken but I am just trying to explain what I am going for. Is it even possible or am I doing things incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing that you want to show a spinner here?
And where's is slow, is it the selector that's slow, or the processing?
If it's the latter, you can do:

```
this.dataSource$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(RecordSelectors.selectActiveItems),
      tap(data => {
        this.store.dispatch(loadingActions.loadingShow()); 

        //DO SOME PROCESSING HERE

        //hide the loading spinner
        this.store.dispatch(loadingActions.loadingHide());
      })
    );
```

Comment: I would like to do something that is needed for this page only such as grouping the results array.